# Decoding UTF-8 strings in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a web crawler in python, and it involves taking headlines from websites.

One of the headlines should've read : And the Hip's coming, too

But instead it said: And the Hipâ€™s coming, too

What's going wrong here?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you included the relevant code, and the particular website you're parsing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to properly decode the source text. Most likely the source text is in UTF-8 format, not ASCII.

Because you do not provide any context or code for your question it is not possible to give a direct answer.

I suggest you study how unicode and character encoding is done in Python:

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Yes, it's UTF-8 treated like Windows 1252: `u'\N{RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK}'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')`.

Answer (score 62):

It's an encoding error -  so if it's a unicode string, this ought to fix it:

```
text.encode("windows-1252").decode("utf-8")
```

If it's a plain string, you'll need an extra step:

```
text.decode("utf-8").encode("windows-1252").decode("utf-8")
```

Both of these will give you a unicode string.

By the way - to discover how a piece of text like this has been mangled due to encoding issues, you can use [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet):

```
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(u"And the Hipâ€™s coming, too")
{'confidence': 0.5, 'encoding': 'windows-1252'}
```

Comment: Small warning: chardet is LGPL-licensed, so that's a consideration if it's going in something that's distributed to end users.