# String of Hex Codes to Non-Latin UTF-8 Characters in Python

Tags: python, bash, pandas, encoding, utf-8

I have a dataframe in which one column contains values starting as

```
b'\xe0\xa4\x9d\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4...'
```

This is how the values look like in the dataframe when I run `df.head(10)`

But when I print this cell using its index number, I get values separated by two backward slashes like this.

```
t = df['text'][461]

"b'\\xe0\\xa4\\xb8\\xe0\\xa5\\x8d\\xe0\\xa4\\xb5\\xe0\\xa4\\xb0\\xe0\\xa5\\x8d\\xe0\\xa4\\xa3\\xe0\\xa4\\xb0\\xe0\\xa5\\x87\\xe0\\xa4\\x96\\xe0\\xa4\\xbe ..."
```

Double quotes show me that my pandas dataframe is taking it as a string and not as a bytes object.

When I searched on the internet and SO, I came to know that is python bytes objects containing hex codes.

I want to convert this column to Non-Latin UTF-8 Characters. 
I tried to do following things.

1. `df['text'][461].decode()`

In this case, I get error as

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

2. `print ("\xe0\xa4\xae\xe0\xa5\x88\xe0\xa4\x82")`

When I manually copied from the dataframe, I get this

`à¤®à¥à¤`

3. `bytes.fromhex('e0a4aee0a588e0a482').decode('utf-8')` 
   In this case, I have to manually remove all the `\x` in the previous code and then I get the correct Hindi (Non-Latin) word which is 
   `'मैं'`

I believe I need to do two things.

1. Ensure that the cell is read as a bytes object and not as a string so that it gets decoded properly.
2. Decode it to non-Latin utf-8

When I tried to convert the object to bytes objects using `bytes(df['text'][461], 'utf-8')`, it just takes the original hex codes string and adds b' to it to make it bytes object and nothing happens thereafter. I am still left with the same /x object.

How do I convert these values to Hindi (non-Latin utf-8) ?

I am now left with no options of how to deal with it. I am very new to encoding, decoding, and hex values.

**EDIT 1**

Using bash shell I was able to remove all extra `"`s from the file and save my column to a different text file. When I ran `file file_name.txt` on Bash, I got `ASCII Text` as the file type. And when I used `iconv` to change the formatting from `ASCII to UTF-8` I still got the same file without any error.

How do I convert this ASCII file to UTF-8, given that `iconv` is not working?

**EDIT 2**

Using `ascii2uni` command in Linux, I got another file which has sequence like `b'à¤ªà¥à¤°à¥ à¤¹à¥ à¤¶à¤¿à¤µà¤­à¤à¥à¤¤à¥à¤ à¤à¥ à¤¹à¤° à¤®à¤¨à¥à¤à¤¾à¤®à¤¨à¤¾'`
When I used bytes.decode() on this, I got following error.

```
SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.
```

Is there anyway I can get it to Hindi?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110629/decoding-utf-8-strings-in-python

Comment: In my program, I mentioned explicitly encoding to utf-8 and also the source where the data is from uses utf-8, I don't know why it downloaded the data like this.

Comment: I don't know Pandas, but to me it looks like the column is stored as `bytes` value, and accessing it through `["text"]` converts it to `str` by simply calling `str(...)` instead of `.decode()`. Can you access the column without triggering the `str`/text conversion and apply `bytes.decode` to it?

Comment: Hi Lenz, I did that and created a list of all the tweets by copying the tweets from actual file, but when I ran `bytes.decode` to it, I got the same error.

Comment: When I copy individual tweet from the csv file and then try to apply the `bytes.decode()` to it, then it is able to do that.