# Tensorflow unicode text encoding-decoding

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, machine-translation

I just started working with cyrillic text. Cannot properly print russian text after text preprocessing. How can I set encoding during text loading?

```
import pathlib
text = pathlib.Path('rus.txt').read_text(encoding='utf-8')

lines = text.splitlines()
pairs = [line.split('\t') for line in lines]
inp = [inp for targ, inp, tag in pairs]
targ = [targ for targ, inp, tag in pairs]
inp[:20]
```

Output1:

```
['Марш!',  'Иди.',  'Идите.',  'Здравствуйте.',  'Привет!',  'Хай.', 
   'Здрасте.',  'Здоро́во!',  'Приветик!',  'Беги!',  'Бегите!',...
```

Creating dataset:

```
BUFFER_SIZE = len (inp)
BATCH_SIZE = 64
    
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inp, targ)).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

for example_input_batch, example_target_batch in dataset.take(1):
  print(example_input_batch[:5]) --Russian input
  print()
  print(example_target_batch[:5]) --English target
  break
```

Output2:

```
 tf.Tensor(
    [b'\xd0\xa2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb \xd1\x85\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x88\xd0\xbe.'
     b'\xd0\xa2\xd1\x8b \xd1\x81\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0 \xd1\x8d\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe \xd1\x81\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb5\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe.'
     b'\xd0\xa2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc \xd0\xb5\xd1\x89\xd1\x91 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd1\x85\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd1\x81\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc.'
     b'\xd0\x94\xd1\x83\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8e, \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbc\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xbe\xd0\xb1 \xd1\x8d\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9 \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5 \xd1\x81 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc.'
     b'\xd0\xaf \xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd1\x83 \xd1\x8d\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe \xd1\x83\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c.'], shape=(5,), dtype=string)

tf.Tensor(
[b'Tom did a good thing.' b'You did that on purpose.'
 b"Tom can't walk on his own yet."
 b"I think it's time for me to talk to the boss about this problem."
 b'I can arrange that.'], shape=(5,), dtype=string)
```

Can you please advise what is the problem here with printing russian text? English text prints ok.

Comment: What is the problem itself? The first output and the second output are structurally not the same. I mean, the first output just has a list of strings, but the second output contains two `tf.Tensors`.

Comment: The problem is in the second output - incorrect russian text output (1st tensor). I can't understand why does it print the russian text with unknown string like '\xd0\xa2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc'. And how can I make it to print properly.

Answer (score 1):

The strings that appear like nonsense are actually UTF-8 encoded.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110629/decoding-utf-8-strings-in-python) for more details.

For example, the first string in the tensor

```
\xd0\xa2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb \xd1\x85\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x88\xd0\xbe.
```

is this garbage

```
Ð¢Ð¾Ð¼ Ð¿Ð¾ÑÑÑÐ¿Ð¸Ð» ÑÐ¾ÑÐ¾
```

which can actually be decoded correctly, like this:

```py
s = '\xd0\xa2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb \xd1\x85\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x88\xd0\xbe.'
decoded = bytes(s, encoding='latin').decode()
print(decoded)
```

Output:

```
Том поступил хорошо.
```

I'm not sure exactly how to do this with Tensorflow, but perhaps [`tf.strings.unicode_decode`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/unicode_decode) can help.

Answer (score 1):

I used `tf.strings.unicode_decode()` function which converts encoded `'\xd0\xa2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc'` like value into a tensors of integers like `[1053, 1077,   32, 1076,...` . I have also converted the result into numpy array to make it applicable for chr() function which converts the unicode integer into unicode symbols.

```
def decode_string(ints):
  strs = [chr(i) for i in ints]
  joined = [''.join(strs)]
  return joined

decoded = tf.strings.unicode_decode(example_input_batch[:5], 'utf-8').numpy()
decoded_list = [decode_string(ex) for ex in decoded]
print(decoded_list)
```

The result is:

```
[['Том был окружён дельфинами.'], ['Бразилия была колонией Португалии.'], ['Скажи Тому, чтобы поторопился.'], ['Я слишком многого прошу?'],...
```